# How to return the average across a number of columns based on a matched row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to return the average of a number of columns into a table matched based on a matched row.

I have a pivot table which includes a list of school names in the rows, and with values listed across the columns. This table varies in the amount of schools included. I am calculating the average of the numbers in each column based on the row.

To combat this problem I am creating another table with all schools included which then matches the name of the school to the the one in the previous table, averaging all the columns in turn, and returning a single value based on the matched school.

So for example:

School Name, 1, 2, 4, 5, ,2, 2.

New Table
School Name, Average
Problem High School, 2.6

I've tried writing a formula but it isn't working as I've planned.

```
=INDEX('IntForecasting - Regional Avg''s'!A3:A420,MATCH(RegionalAverageAutomations!A4,schoolavgcalc,0),AVG(B:BE))
```

I am expecting the above code to match the school name in my pivot table, to the school name inside my newly created table, and then return the average of columns B through to BE, for the row matched based on the school.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what tabs you're dealing with, but in principle you just need an `INDEX`/`MATCH` within an `AVERAGE`, something like this:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:C,MATCH("school 1",A:A,0),))
```

[image]

Replace `B:C` with your columns `B:BE`, `"school 1"` with `RegionalAverageAutomations!A4`, and `A:A` with the column of school names in the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks this worked!

I'm now trying to find a way to set the "B:C" to the length of columns in the pivot table, so that when the column length changes so does the formula.

Any idea how I'd implement this?

Comment: `AVERAGE` should ignore blank columns, so what if you just extend the range past the maximum number of columns you have in the pivot table?